# Trouble setting selected item in <Select>

Tags: vue.js

I am looking to auto fill form data based on a table row selection. My problem is I cannot set the correct Selected item in  input boxes

I have tried using v-model (as below). I have also tried using

Html Input:

```
<select @change="typeSelected(selectedType)" v-model="selectedType">
        <option v-for="type in types" v-bind:key="type.id" v-bind:value="type.id">{{ type.name }}</option>
    </select>
```

Vue function to update the selected item

```
public setSelected(type: AssetTypeDto | undefined){
        if(type) {
            this.selectedType = type;
        }
    }
```

Also i tried   `<option :selected="type.id === selectedType.id"`. This didn't work either

Comment: Also tried ** = <option :selected="type.id === selectedType.id". This didnt work either.

Comment: You don't need a `@change="typeSelected(selectedType)"` as the v-model will automatically set itself to the selected value